# expressjs ignore next functions till reach spezified function

Tags: node.js, express

I have a queue of functions called through next. In normal case everything is ok, but I have a spezial scenario, i want to call the same url but do not want to step trough all this function. some functions in the middle of queue should not call.

I hope it is understandable what I mean.

So I want to tell next function to ignore the next function till reach function x. The only thing i could found was next('route') but it jump only to the last function in queue.

Answer (score 0):

Attach some flag variable in your request object

```
function first(req,res,next){
if(your scenario)
 req.flag = true;
}
```

Check for that variable inside other middlewares(functions)

```
function second(req,res,next){
 if(req.flag) return next();
}
```

Passing data inside next wont work because next takes error as parameter and it will reach your error handling middleware

Comment: ok thank you, it is what i think about too, but hope there is a easier way.